# Obter dados de um site para usar em C#

Tags: html, c#

Boa noite,

Sou iniciante, e estou desenvolvendo um programa em C# no Visual Studio para o meu TCC, esse trecho do código que estou com problema vai obter os dados de uma tabela de um site e depois de armazená-los em algum componente, talvez um DataGridView. O problema é que não estou conseguindo obter os dados, estou utilizando a HTML Agility Pack, porém não entendo quase nada de HTML. Já vi alguns tutoriais, documentação e nada... O código abaixo até que executa, porém retorna vazio, como se não houvesse nada naquele trecho do site. Há alguma peculiaridade nesse site que impede essa extração de dados?

Inspecionei pelo navegador para pegar as informações para usar no código (eu não coloquei o código em html aqui porque não encontrei uma opção para copiar o código inteiro no navegador, mas anexei uma imagem).

Os dados que preciso são 3 inteiros referentes aos volumes de chuva e o nome da cidade (opcional). Não preciso do código pronto, mas qualquer dica que puder me direcionar será de muita ajuda. Obrigado desde já pela atenção.

```
public class HtmlProcessar
{
    public string ProcessHtmlCode()
    {
        //Carrega o conteúdo da URL do Site
        const string html = "http://www.funceme.br/app-calendario/dia/municipios/media/1974/1/1";
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);

        var htmlBody = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");

        var node = htmlBody.Element("app-root");
        string saida = node.InnerHtml;
        return saida;
    }

}
```

[image: Código HTML do Site da Funceme - Link está no código acima]

Comment: na verdade não precisa disso pra esse caso, existe uma API pra esse site, muito mais confiável dessa forma: http://api.funceme.br/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No código html do site note que você tem `<app-root></app-root>`
e é justamente onde se encontra o conteúdo geral do site.
Parece que a página do site é gerada através de javascript/wasm para então exibir.
Nesse caso o certo é usar API, e se ainda não for possível, terá que rodar uma instância offscreen de navegador para abrir o site e renderizar o html, sendo esse o caso, eu recomendaria o CEFSharp

Answer (score 1):

Olá, boa tarde!

Como o Marcus falou, a página é gerada através de Javascript.
Você tera que utilizar uma ferramenta como o Selenium por exemplo.

Fiz um teste aqui no xPath:

```
/html/body/app-root/app-root/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/div/app-calendario-dia/mat-card/mat-card-content/div/div[2]/app-calendario-tabela/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]
```

e retornou dado.

Um abraço!